# h:commandButton not working action

Tags: java, jsf-2

I don't know what I'm missing but h:commandButton not working, I cannot call method "viewDetail".

- jsf-api-2.1.jar
- jsf-impl-2.1.jar

default.xhtml (template page)

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
      >
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
 <ui:insert name="content">Template content will be inserted here.</ui:insert>
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

loadData.xhtml (child page)

```
<ui:composition>
<ui:define name="content">
<ui:repeat id="dtbEmployee" var="item" value="#{viewEmployee.mxoEmployeeDtos}" varStatus="status">
 <a onclick="document.getElementById('dtbEmployee:#{status.index}:btnView').click();">
Click to view data</a>
<h:commandButton id="btnView" style="display: none" immediate="true">
   <f:ajax event="click" render="dtbEmployee" execute="dtbEmployee" listener="#{viewEmployee.viewDetail(item)}" />
</h:commandButton> 

</ui:repeat>
</ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

viewEmployee.java (call method page)

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@Named
@RequestScoped

public class ViewEmployee implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public void viewDetail(EmployeeDto employeeDTO) {
        log.info("------------Call detail------------------");        
  }

}
```

Comment: What does "*can not call method*" actually mean?

Comment: means viewDetail method not invoked when I click button

Answer (score 0):

At first glance you have:

```
#viewEmployee.viewDetail(item)}
```

and it should be:

```
#{viewEmployee.viewDetail(item)}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is my mistake when copy, but the my project still correct standard EL

Comment: I have found the problem come from ui:repeat tag, still finding what happening...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my strange problem...

in ui:repeat tag dont call value from get set method, call direct method.

Ex:.

```
viewCustomer.java
public List<CustomerDto> listCustomer() {
        return listCustomerDto;
}


view.xhtml
<ui:repeat value="#{viewCustomer.listCustomer()}" var="item" varStatus="status">
```